# Replace ISNULL function in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was asked to rewrite the below queries by eliminating the `ISNULL` Function in where clause due to performance issues. How can I rewrite the below queries by replacing the `ISNULL` Function in `WHERE` clause and in `JOIN` condition. Below are the sample queries.

```
Select * 
from child c 
inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id  
where ISNULL(p.ParentId, 0) <> 0  

Select * 
from child c 
inner join Parent P on isnull(c.Parentid,0)=p.id

select * 
from parent 
where isnull(Status, '') != 'Active'

Select * 
from child c 
inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id 
where CAST(P.PostedDate AS DATE) 
      BETWEEN CAST(isnull(@FromDate,P.PostedDate) AS DATE) 
          AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)

SELECT * 
FROM TEMP 
WHERE EDATE=ISNULL(@EDATE,EDATE)
```

Comment: Use AND/OR instead.

Comment: Replacing isnull is not always faster

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can simply remove the `isnull` function, and it need not be replaced by anything. For example:

```
select * 
from parent 
where isnull(Status, '') != 'Active'
```

Can be rewritten as

```
select * 
from parent 
where Status != 'Active'
```

Since if `Status` is null, the comparison still returns `FALSE`. The rule is: 
NULL = value: NULL (interpreted as FALSE, since it is not TRUE).

If NULL has to be included in your results, you can add `Attribute/@Variable IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from child c inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id where ISNULL(p.ParentId, 0) <> 0
```

Here, neither you need `ISNULL` nor any alternative of this because in this case

`NULL <> 0` will be `FALSE` similarly `0 <> 0` also `FALSE`

`NULL = NULL` will be `FALSE` if the setting `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` else `TRUE`

And here, the alternative of this is,

If you want to return `NULL` as `TRUE` then you can use

```
WHERE (p.ParentId IS NULL OR p.ParentId <> 0)
```

Otherwise,

```
(p.ParentId <> 0 OR 0 <> 0) --But it doesn't have any meaning and it's exactly same to simply use p.ParentId <> 0
```

You can handle `ISNULL` accordingly in your all the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Be carefull with this
Look at this example :

```
declare @table table(ID int, status varchar(50))

insert into @Table (ID, status)
values (1, 'active'), (2, ''), (3, null), (4, 'active')

select t.*
from   @Table t
where  t.status <> 'active'
```

This will return just one record (ID: 2)

while this

```
select t.*
from   @Table t
where  isnull(t.status, '') <> 'active'
```

will return 2 records (ID: 2 and 3)

So it depends on what you want in your result set, do you want records where the field Status is null also returned or not ?
In case you dont want them then the answer is simple

```
select t.*
from   @Table t
where  t.status <> 'active'
```

Otherwise you need something like this
Since the original query had IsNull in it, I suspect this is what you want.

```
select t.*
from   @Table t
where (t.status is null or t.status <> 'active')
```

This does not use the IsNull() but I am not sure if much performance will be gained here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
Select * from child c inner join Parent P 
on c.id=p.id OR where p.ParentId IS NULL

Select * from child c inner join Parent P on c.Parentid=p.id OR c.ParentId IS NULL

select * from parent 
where [Status] != 'Active' AND [Status] IS NOT NULL

Select * from child c inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id 
where 
    ( (P.PostedDate) BETWEEN CAST(@FromDate) AS DATE) AND @FromDate IS NOT NULL  AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) )
OR 
    ( (P.PostedDate) BETWEEN P.PostedDate AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) )

SELECT * FROM TEMP 
WHERE EDATE = CASE WHEN @EDATE IS NULL THEN EDATE ELSE @EDATE END
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute as below to make SARGABLE:

```
    where ISNULL(p.ParentId, 0) <> 0 --- where p.ParentId = 0 or p.ParentID is null
    Select * from child c inner join Parent P on isnull(c.Parentid,0)=p.id --- Select * from child c inner join Parent P on c.Parentid = p.id OR (c.Parentid is null and p.id = 0)
    where isnull(Status, '') != 'Active' --- where Status <> 'Active'
    where CAST(P.PostedDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(isnull(@FromDate,P.PostedDate) AS DATE) AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) --- where P.PostedDate BETWEEN isnull(@FromDate,P.PostedDate) AND @ToDate
    WHERE EDATE=ISNULL(@EDATE,EDATE) --- WHERE @EDATE IS NULL OR EDATE = @EDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

When values can be null you have to use the Three-value logic.
[Read this article.](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)
So if you want to make your arguments SARGABLE avoiding to use ISNULL or COALESCE functions, you have to combine OR/AND/NOT/CASE operators, depending on logic of your query

In your examples:

```
Select * 
from child c 
inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id  
-- where ISNULL(p.ParentId, 0) <> 0 
where p.ParentId <> 0  -- when p.ParentId is null condition is evaluated as unknown and record are excluded.



Select * 
from child c 
-- inner join Parent P on isnull(c.Parentid,0)=p.id
inner join Parent P on (c.Parentid=p.id) OR (c.Parentid IS NULL AND p.id = 0) 

select * 
from parent 
--where isnull(Status, '') != 'Active'
where Status IS NULL OR Status <> 'Active'


-- IN THIS CASE YOU HAVE NO BENEFIT BECAUSE CONVERSIONS MAKES YOUR ARGUMENTS NOT SARGABLE!!! 
Select * 
from child c 
inner join Parent P on c.id=p.id 
where CAST(P.PostedDate AS DATE) 
      BETWEEN CAST(CASE WHEN @FromDate IS NULL THEN P.PostedDate ELSE @FromDate END) AS DATE) 
          AND CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)



SELECT * 
FROM TEMP 
--WHERE EDATE=ISNULL(@EDATE,EDATE)
WHERE EDATE=@EDATE
```